# i need help outputting

Tags: mysql, database, output

I tried using where does not exist code but i'm having troubles using it.

i need to output `quantity` on 3rd row but quantity is on other table on sql. how do i call it to output on this table? below where the pictures of the data tables.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("../../../connection.php");

$sql = mysqli_query($query, "SELECT * 
                   FROM `orders` 
                   INNER JOIN `order_track` ON `orders`.`order_id` = `order_track`.`order_id` 
                   WHERE `order_track`.`t2` = 'inactive' 
                   ORDER BY `orders`.`order_date` DESC");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($sql)) {
    echo "<tr>
          <td>$row[0]</td>
          <td>$row[1]</td>
          <td>$row[]</td>
          <td><button type='button' class='btn btn-success' onClick=\"approval('".$row[0]."')\">Approve</button></td>
         </tr>";
} 
?>
```

[ordered_product (table)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO1st.png)

[image: ordered_product]

[orders (table)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3c8W.png)

[ouputted table where i need to output quantity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJkjR.png)

Comment: Your query is not even selecting from table ordered_product: start with that using the appropriate join clause. If you still have an issue then you can ask about that.

Comment: problem is i already used innier join on verifying shippng

Comment: If you could omit the PHP codes and update a SQL Fiddle and not the table images , it would be lot easier to help.

Comment: im stucked where to call product_quantity on the code where ordered_product has no relation to orders table. I already used innerjoin for aprroval.